Add Payment Method on my SAAS using an API from local gateway
I have a SAAS program on Django and Python, that manage Clients accounts (one or many).
As for now, we handle all payment manually, adding a new client manually to reoccurring monthly payment 3'rd party system
For a client with many accounts we have a payment calculator and we charge the amount manually.
The major issue we handle is that each month most of our clients have different payment cost, according to number of accounts running.

we don't have Stripe here.

So my Questions are of 2 types, the way to calculate the payments and the way to execute it.

is it safe to add a payment gateway by a simple API, and handle the payment from the backend of the server side ? is it done with a cron job kind of tasker?
this it the API:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/16363118/TzkyNLWB
how can I calculate the payment monthly, should I make a smart way to do it, are there more existing solution for the case ? for example an account was running 1.7-5.7 stopped and resumed in 15.7-30.7 is there an recommended algorithm for storing the data?
We charge clients world wide.
how to manage all payments ?
how to enable more payment ways, Paypal for example ?
how can I charge a client that added one account in 15.7.24 and another in 20.7.24, and to have 1 invoice for him ? should I charge him one time at the end of month ? may I need to make sure to get some balance before I start the first account (so I wont get to 30.7.24 and the payment dont work).

What big SAAS company normally work with without increasing the cost per charge from 0.75% to 3% like using Stripe or Bluesnap?

Almost all payment gateway works, similar way. You make call to their API, then you redirect to a secure form, to allow clients to fill in their card details and make payment. You can specify if it a recurring charge using their API itself, so it automatically gets charged.
In your case the charge would be no_accounts x fixed price. Many payment gateways allows multiple payment method, and gateways like stripe are available in almost all countries. I would suggest make your pricing simpler, like a package providing access to a team of 5. (they get charged the same if they have 3 or 5)

@Art the thing is that we already handle 2000 clients, so changing it to package based, is not best practice, what if I need a metric base charges ? what can I use for that ? is a simple call to payment gateway using an api, is a good option ? what about fail charges ? how can I manage it without building the whole system from scratch ?

You don't have to build the entire thing from scratch, use only Payment gateway APIs  to collect payment, they have already done all the heavy lifting. If you are making a usage based pricing calculate the usage for example no_of_hrs x fixed_price or so and then pass that price to the API. First you make call to their API and then redirect them to a secure form, then listen to webhook events to confirm transaction.
Check out this article

I believe stripe doesn't charge you for failed charges, not sure about others. Check out stripe pricing page
